# insert concatenated value to db

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i have a form with first name, last name, college, and gender. i want them to be inserted to my table in my db but at the same time it will record a username that is derived from a concatenated value from the input college and last name.

fields in form: firstname, lastname, college, gender

fields in table: firstname, lastname, college, gender, username

here is my code:

```
$college=$_POST['college'];
$lastname=$_POST['lname'];

$sql="INSERT INTO name (fname, lname, college, gender, username)
VALUES

('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[college]', '$_POST[".$college."". $lastname."]')";
```

'$_POST[".$college."". $lastname."]' <--this is the supposed to be username.

im sorry for this elementary question and my confusing way of asking. Thanks !!

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) alert!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
$userName = $_POST['college'].''.$_POST['lastname'];
$sql="INSERT INTO name (fname, lname, college, gender, username) VALUES
('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[college]', '$userName')";
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

There is no point in storing such a username in the table.
You can (and should) compose it any time you need it from first name and last name

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO name (fname, lname, college, gender, username)
VALUES

  ( '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[gender]', '$_POST[college]',
    CONCAT(college, lname)
  )";
```

But as @Col. Shrapnel pointed, there is rarely a good reason for storing such information (twice) in the database.

Answer (score 0):

`$college.$lastname` is what you're looking for